# when do setTimeOut callback function get its parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I'm a little confused on how setTimeOut works:
why the callback function didn't got the values it needed when it was invoked, but got them from the bottom of the script?

I expected it to print 5 and not 7..

what am I missing ?

any help is appreciated, thanks!

```js
let foo = () => {
  console.log(x);
};

let x = 5;
setTimeout(foo, 0); //7
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {} //just to waste some time because the timeOut is actually 4ms
x = 7;
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {} //just to waste some time because the timeOut is actually 4ms` This doesn't work the way you want it to. The timeout won't run as long as this loop is blocking the event loop.

Comment: Run this code on https://www.jsv9000.app/ to see how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callback function of the `setTimeout` isn't executed *until* the **call stack is empty** and the call stack won't be empty until the execution of your synchronous javascript code completes.

As the last statement overwrites the value of `x`, when the callback function of `setTimeout` is invoked, it logs the latest value, i.e. 7.

It seems that you are expecting the callback function of `setTimeout` to be executed while the `for` loop is executing BUT that's not how Javascript works.

Once the timer of the `setTimeout` expires, callback function of the `setTimeout` is enqueued in the task queue. From the task queue, event loop will push this callback on the call stack BUT the callback function won't be pushed on the call stack *until* no other javascript code is executing, i.e. the **call stack is empty**.

It doesn't matters how long it takes for the synchronous script execution to end; no scheduled callback will be executed until the synchronous script execution ends.

Keep in mind that all your code executes on a **single thread**.

Also note that the number of milliseconds passed to `setTimeout` is **NOT** the exact time after which the callback function will be executed; it's the *minimum* time after which the callback function will be invoked.